# Merge Sort tracing clarification

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm having a little difficulty of tracing the process of merge sort...
Conceptually, I understand that an unsorted array will be divided until its sub-arrays of sub-arrays become the length of 1, in which it becomes an array that contains 1 elements each, that is said to be sorted. 
Using

```
 mergeSort(A,p,r) //where p = lowest index, r = highest
     if (p < r) {
         q = (p+r) / 2
         mergeSort(A,p,q)
         mergeSort(A,q+1,r)
         merge(A,p,q,r) 
     }
```

on an unsorted array of say [3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 4] where p is an index at element 3, q being an index of element 2 and r being the index at element 4. From my understanding,
it will first be divided into [3, 5, 2] due to invoking mergeSort(A,p,q); now the new indices will be p at element 3, q at element 5, r at element 2; so [3, 5, 2] will be divided to [3, 5] with p and q being indices at element 3, r being index at element 5; which will be divided to [3]. My question is, is [2] (which is from [3, 5, 2] after division) be of indexed as p or q+1?

.... Actually, I feel like my question isn't clear enough so to ask it in another way,
since [3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 4] will be divided into [3, 5, 2] and [1, 6, 4]; which will be divided into [3, 5] and [2] ; [1, 6] and [4]; which will also be divided to [3] [5] and [1] [6]; which part of the divisions invoke mergeSort(A,p,q) and which part of the division invoke mergeSort(A,q+1,r)? are [1, 6, 4] also indexed as p at element 1, r at element 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to track this is take a pencil and paper. And do it for yourself.

Any rule to follow? Yes when you call a function then that funstion is executed. (or your attention should be in that function) .

What I mean is:-

`mergesort([3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 4])` you called.

Then eventually you face this line

```
     q = (p+r) / 2
     mergeSort(A,p,q)   [3,5,2] <------
     mergeSort(A,q+1,r) [1,6,4]
     merge(A,p,q,r)
```

Now your attention should be in 
`mergesort( [3,5,2] )`

This way you will go on. And at some point you will reach this line.

```
     q = (p+r) / 2
     mergeSort(A,p,q)   [2,3,5] // this is sorted now
     mergeSort(A,q+1,r) [1,6,4] <--------
     merge(A,p,q,r)
```

And go on like this. This way you at one point will invoke `merge` which will merge the sorted subarrays into the complete sorted array.

- Don't bother yourself `mergeSort(A,q+1,r)` when you are sorting `mergeSort(A,p,q)`. This si seuqntially processed not parallely so unless this subarray is sorted the other portion is not called.

---

As answer to your second question let me show you another picture.

```
 [3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 4]
  p     q        r
       /\
[3,5,2]  [1, 6, 4]
 p q r    p  q  r
  |   \       |    \ 
[3,5] [2]  [1, 6]  [4]
 p r        p  r
 q          q
 /  \        |\
[3] [5]     [1] [6]
```

This is the way the mergesort are called on the array.

And in recusrion every function call has its own parameters. What serves as q in the parent array in child array it will serve as `p`  or `r`.